# jqtouch/sencha touch & pdf's

Tags: iphone, ipad, jqtouch, sencha-touch

I need to create a PDF viewer with scrolling, zooming and swipes for the iOS family of devices... I've played around using iframes and objects and I've had no luck on making anything decent.

I guess I am looking for a few pointers, clues or code snippets to get PDF's looking good on iOS devices using UIWebView.

Any comment would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Eek. If you plan to release this on any of the app stores/marketplaces, I wouldn't do this on a web-app platform simply for performance reasons. My experience with performance has always been better writing natively. You may find some implementations of what you're looking for either in or built upon those frameworks, but if you want the smoothest user experience, I'd go native.

Even simple UI elements like lists and buttons just don't seem to render or respond as fast as web apps. You're basically wrapping HTML5, JS, and CSS in a framework, then wrapping in PhoneGap or an instance of a webkit webview, then executing in Java or Objective-C... you get the idea. Just a lot of extra overhead.

However, if this is going to be released as a web-app accessible from the web (and not from within a native app), then you may no choice but to experiment and optimize the heck out of everything you can.

Just my two bits.

Comment: I figured as much once I got going. Thanks!